# explode textarea and commas

Tags: php, array, csv

Am attempting to recreate a common feature, where a user can type several items in to a textarea, separated by commas and newlines and then submit them, i.e. for multiple record entry.

The data does not come from a CSV file and is manually entered.

```
// data looks like this in the textarea:

Widget 1, 4, 10
Widget 2, 1.3, 10
Widget 3, 5.5, 15
```

Then submit the form:

```
$products = explode("\r\n", $_POST['productsTextarea']); // sanitize

$y = 0; 
$productArray = array();

// explode and trim each product, assign values to an array
foreach($products as $product) :      
    $product = array_map('trim', explode(',', $product));
    $productArray[$y]['name'] = $product [0];
    $productArray[$y]['cost'] = $product [1];
    $productArray[$y]['quantity'] = $product [2];
    $y++;
endforeach;
```

-

```
// desired output of $productArray
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'name' => 'Widget 1',
        'cost' => '4',
        'quantity' => '10',
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'name' => 'Widget 2',
        'cost' => '1.3',
        'quantity' => '10',
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'name' => 'Widget 3',
        'cost' => '5.5',
        'quantity' => '15',
    ),
)
```

I feel this isn't particularly extensible (i.e. the array keys are hard coded) and wonder how it would cope with a lot of items.

```
Name, Cost, Quantity, Colour, Location, Postcode // header row?
Widget 1, 4, 10, blue, Foo, Bar
Widget 2, 4, 10, red, Foo, Bar
```

Comment: Welcome to [codereview.se]! IMO your question is off-topic as of our [help/on-topic]. Here on [codereview.se] we do not help with the implementation of new features, as you describe it. For questions like these you should try a different site. I suggest [so], but must insist on that you read through their [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question there ;)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! IMO your question is on-topic. I consider this not to be an implementation of a new feature but to make an existing feature more extensible.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract class is ideal for this:

```
abstract class ProductsTextareaBase {

  protected abstract function getColumns();

  public function parse($productsTextarea) {
    $products = explode("\r\n", $productsTextarea); // sanitize

    $y = 0; 
    $productArray = array();

    // explode and trim each product, assign values to an array
    foreach($products as $product) {      
        $product = array_map('trim', explode(',', $product));
        $i = 0;
        $columns = $this->getColumns();
        foreach($product as $col) {
          $productArray[$y][$columns[$i]] = $col;
          $i++;
        }
        $y++;
    }
    return $productArray;
  }
}

class WidgetProductsTextarea extends ProductsTextareaBase {
  protected function getColumns() {
    return array('name', 'cost', 'quantity');
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really. Composition over Inheritance wins in this case.